# how to make the images always in center

Tags: html, css

I want to put 6 images in this page, and need to be the max number of photos in one line is 3 and min is 2, when I increase or decrease the browser size.

How make the size of the image get bigger or smaller when I increase or decrease the browser size?

---

This is my css stylesheet what i need to add

```
div.img
{
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 0px solid #0000ff;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}   
div.img img
{
  display: inline;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
div.img a:hover img {border: 1px solid #0000ff;}
div.desc
{
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Create a JSFiddle please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to do this is to use:

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

also dont forget to make sure that your containing element has:

```
text-align:center;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Good answer! Lacked only explain why this: `margin:0 auto;` works with "blocks-elements", `text-align` works with "inline-elements".

Comment: That's a good point! I'm still getting used to writing well structured answers! Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

set margin auto your main div

```
 margin:auto;
```